# MySQL super slow inner join with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I'm having a problem joining the 2 tables below. What I need is all of the parts in the first table where the clei OR part number is found in the second table, with a count of how many matches there are from table 1.

```
===================           ===================
table: svi                    table: svp
===================           ===================
id                            id
po                            price
customer                      clei
clei                          partNumber
partNumber                    description
====================          ===================
```

svi has about 1 million rows. svp has about 2000. Here is the join that I'm using...

```
SELECT svi.clei,
       svi.partNumber,
       count(*)
FROM    svp svp
   INNER JOIN
      svi svi
   ON    (svp.clei = svi.clei)
         OR (svp.partNumber = svi.partNumber)
GROUP BY svi.partNumber
```

The query is taking a little over 2 minutes to run, which seems ridiculously slow. clei and partNumber are indexed in both tables. What else can I do to speed up this join?

Comment: (off-topic) If `partNumber` is not the `PK` of table `svi` then your query is invalid SQL. Even if MySQL accepts it, it takes the freedom to return whatever value it wants for the expression `svi.clei` from the `SELECT` clause. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` is also missing one of the non-aggregate columns in your `SELECT` clause

Comment: Yes Phil, that is intentional. Each partNumber can only have 1 clei, but each clei can have many partNumbers. Grouping by partNumber only works to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: Then it seems like you would get the same answer if the `ON` checked only `clei` and not  `partNumber`??

Answer (score 0):

The indexes don't help very much here because there are no `WHERE` conditions against constants and because of the `OR` operator.

All the 2000 rows of the `svp` table are read; conditions against constants reduce the number of rows read from a table but there is no such condition here.

Then, for each of these 2000 rows, one or two lookups are performed in the indexes of the `svi` table to identify the matching rows. One for `clei` and, if it doesn't succeed, another one for `partNumber`. Or viceversa.

A compound index on columns `clei` and `partNumber` on table `svi` doesn't help here; it helps when the conditions are combined using `OR`.

The indexes on table `svp` are not used. If there is an index on `svp` that contains both `clei` and `partNumber` columns then MySQL can decide to read it here just because it contains less data than the entire table. But it still reads the entire index and processes all the rows. It cannot use the index to filter rows because there is no filtering on `svp`.

It could be worse (read the entire `svi` table and use the indexes on `svp` for lookup) but MySQL is smart enough to process the smaller table first.

Put `EXPLAIN` in front of your query and MySQL [tells you (in less words)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) what I tried to explain above.

---

As I also said in a comment, the query is invalid SQL. For one value of `svi.partNumber` you probably have more than one value for `svi.clei`. The `GROUP BY svi.partNumber` clause generates a single output row from all the rows it gets from table `svi` that have the same value for `partNumber`.

But, since there are two or more different values for `clei` for the same `partNumber`, the final value it pics for the expression `svi.clei` from the `SELECT` clause is indeterminate. This means it can change if you run the same query again later or if you run it on a different server that mirrors the database (or after the database is backed up then restored from the backup).

If you just forgot to add `svi.clei` in the `GROUP BY` clause then it's an easy fix but otherwise you have to re-think your query because as it is now, it doesn't produce the results you expect.

Comment: I intentionally left out svi.clei from the group by clause, as there can be multiple partNumbers for a single clei. For example, 3 different parts could look like this....

CLEI/PartNumber
BAC3SY4EAB/11540A-REV-01
BAC3SY4EAB/11540A-REV-02
BAC3SY4EAB/11540A-REV-03

So I want to know if I have 8 of the first, 10 of the second, and 4 or the third.

Comment: And the query seems to be valid, as I get back accurate results each time it runs. It is just excruciatingly slow.

Comment: If you have multiple `partNumber`s for a single `clei` it works as expected (but it's still invalid SQL). You can put `svi.clei` in the `GROUP BY` clause after `svi.partNumber`. While this fixes the query, it doesn't improve its speed :-( The problem appears when it's the other way around: one `partNumber`, multiple values for `clei`.

Comment: Okay, but it's not possible for a partNumber to have multiple values for clei. I'm not concerned about the validity of my query. I posted here to find a faster solution, even if it's a completely different query.

Comment: If I take out the group by and the count(*), then it executes in 0.32 seconds. There has to be a faster way to get a count of the matches.

Comment: The validity of your query is more important than you think. It allows you to run it on other RDBMSes (only MySQL allows it) but this probably won't happen. And it allows you to sleep well, without the fear that it will stop working when you upgrade to [MySQL 5.7.5 or newer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: Regarding the speed, I really don't know why it takes so long. In theory, if you remove the `GROUP BY` clause and the `COUNT(*)` expression, it should read the same amount of rows from the tables, only produce different output results. Does the grouping require so much hard work?!